# Streamlit pandas date format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, streamlit

No matter what I do, streamlit displays my pandas date columns as below:
[image]

However, when printing the columns in my terminal they come out as '2023-05-11' and '11 May 23'.

This is the function I'm using to convert the datetime columns into the date columns:

```
    def _get_date(self):
        self.df["Date"] = (
            pd.to_datetime(self.df[self.date], utc=True)
            .dt.tz_convert("Europe/London")
            .dt.date
        )
        self.df["Test"] = pd.to_datetime(self.df["Date"], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime('%d %b %y')
        self.df['Test2'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['Datetime'])
        self.df["Test2"] = self.df['Test2'].astype(str)
        self.df["Test2"] = [d[0] for d in self.df["Test2"].str.split(" ")]
```

When printing the dataframe in my console this is what I see instead:

[image]

The original Datetime column is in this format
'2023-05-11T18:00:00.000+01:00'

**UPDATE:**

I now know what's causing this conversion. I've been using from `streamlit_extras.dataframe_explorer import dataframe_explorer`
which apparently looks for all date columns and turns them back into the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.

Comment: streamlit must be doing an internal conversion that is independent of the pre-existing pandas format

Comment: How do you call `_get_date`?

Comment: _get_date() is part of a processing class. I removed 'self' to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to test a simple example like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': ['2023-05-11T18:00:00.000+01:00', '2023-05-12T18:00:00.000+01:00']})
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])
df['Date'] = df['Datetime'].dt.strftime('%d %b %y')

st.dataframe(df)
```

[image]

---

<s>You have to return the dataframe. The modifications are not in-place:</s>

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

# Initial state
df = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': ['2023-05-12', '2023-05-06']})
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])

def _get_date(df):
     df["Date"] = (
            pd.to_datetime(df["Datetime"], utc=True)
            .dt.tz_convert("Europe/London")
            .dt.date
        )
     df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime('%d %b %y')
     df["Date"] = df["Date"].astype(str)
     df["Test"] = df["Date"].copy()
     return df  # <- HERE

st.dataframe(_get_date(df))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm able to reproduce your result. However the difference here I think is the initial type of Datetime. My Datetime is of the form '2023-05-11T18:00:00.000+01:00'.

Comment: I tried with your input and it works as expected. I see you found the solution, right?

Comment: Yes turns out it was just streamlit_extras library converting it back to the format displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `_get_date` function, is currently making both the "Date" and "Test" columns show the same thing. If you expected them to show different values, you could do it like this:

```py
def _get_date(df):
    df["Date"] = (
        pd.to_datetime(df["Datetime"], utc=True).dt.tz_convert("Europe/London").dt.date
    )
    df["Test"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%Y-%m-%d").dt.strftime("%d %b %y")
    df["Date"] = df["Date"].astype(str)
```

In this version the "Date" column shows the format `2023-05-11` and the "Test" shows `11 May 23`.
[image]